VSCode not opening large file
I need to open a file in VSCode the problem is that the files is 22,5GB and I am getting the oom error. It is always loading until it reaches 15GB RAM usages and than crashes. I have over 35GB free RAM so memory shouldn't be a problem. Anyone know how to solve this?
I have the large file optimilization checkbox on.
Opening via cmd with --max-memory=35840mb did not help.

Try disabling all extensions and opening the file. If that works, reenable extensions until it fails.
